send request by prisma to db to sort data
Let’s say there are 7k objects in the database that have a pair field and only 1k unique pair fields, respectively, each field is duplicated 7 times. The task is to return an array of 1000 objects from 7k fields, filtered by the minimum price among all fields with the same pair field. access to the database must be done through prisma.js. but an sql query will be also fine. example:
that is how fields looks in db:
[
  {
    pair: 'btcusdt',
    price: 20,
    createdAt: 2020-01-01,
  },
  {
    pair: 'btcusdt',
    price: 2,
    createdAt: 2020-01-03,
  },
  {
    pair: 'btcusdt',
    price: 1,
    createdAt: 2020-01-02,
  },
  {
    pair: 'ethusdt',
    price: 40,
    createdAt: 2020-01-03,
  },
  {
    pair: 'ethusdt',
    price: 2,
    createdAt: 2020-01-21,
  },
  {
    pair: 'ethusdt',
    price: 9,
    createdAt: 2020-01-12,
  },
  {
    pair: 'bnbusdt',
    price: 1,
    createdAt: 2020-01-1,
  },
  {
    pair: 'bnbusdt',
    price: 0.6,
    createdAt: 2020-01-22,
  },
  {
    pair: 'bnbusdt',
    price: 0.01,
    createdAt: 2020-01-03,
  },
]

the problem is that this request returned fields sorted by price but also by createdAt
Thats how response should look:
[
  {
    pair: 'btcusdt',
    minPrice: 1,
    createdAt: 2020-01-02,
  },
  {
    pair: 'ethusdt',
    price: 2,
    createdAt: 2020-01-21,
  },
  {
    pair: 'bnbusdt',
    price: 0.01,
    createdAt: 2020-01-03,
  },
]

the request that i used:
const maxPrices = await prismaClient[exchange].groupBy({
          by: ["pair"],
          _max: {
            price: true,
            createdAt: true,
          },
          where: {
            createdAt: {
              gt: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * dumpPeriod),
            },
          },
        });```


Please clarify what fields you want the result to be sorted by.

I want the fields to be sorted only by the price field

What about minPrice? One of your sample objects has that property, but no price. The more information and most of all, accurate information you provide, the easier it is for people to help you.
